# How can I show autocomplete errors

Tags: reactjs, forms, controller, material-ui, react-hook-form

I'm working with React Hook Forms.

```
<Controller
  control={control}
  rules={{ required: "Required" }}
  error={errors.state ? true : false}
  helperText={errors.state && errors.state.message}
  name="state"
  as={
    <AutoComplete
      options={stateOptions}
      onChange={selectStateHandler}
      label="State"
      value={selectedState}
    />
  }
/>
```

helper text is working with `TextField` but not with `Autocomplete`. `TextField` border color changes on error, I want same with `Autocomplete`.

Answer (score 39):

`Autocomplete` render input using `TextField`, so you just have to do the same with text field to show error

```js
<Autocomplete
  ...
  renderInput={(params) => (
    <TextField
      error={true}
      helperText="Example error"
      {...params}
      label="Combo box"
      variant="outlined"
    />
  ...
  )}
/>
```

Below is the preview codesandbox

[image: Edit Material demo]

Comment: is there any way to display the `helperText` only when the error occurs?

Comment: @JayeshBabu you could do something like `helperText={error ? "Example error" : ""}`